# Color meaning of Redmine Gantt Chart?

Tags: redmine

Where I can read about color meaning on redmine Gantt chart ?
the bar (for certain issue) can be as grey, green, red or blue :)

But what does it mean (each color)? Below is a real screenshot from our project portal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Green is the amount of the issue/activity which you have completed.
Red is the part of the activity which you have NOT completed AND that it was supposed to be already done (before today).
Grey is an activity which has not been done but it was planned to be done in the future.